# ES 6 modules reimport

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource, vue-component

If i import my modules from my main.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from './vuex/store'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource);

import Component from './components/component.vue';
```

In this example, do i need to reimport VueResource in my component.js ?

If not i don't understand why i have an error when i want to use vue ressource in my component.js :

```
Cannot read property '$http' of undefined
```

component.js :

```
this.$http.get('http://ajaxurl.test').then((response) => {
        // success callback


    }, (response) => {
        //failure

    });
```

Comment: You say `component.js` and `component.vue`. Which is it? Can you show more of the component? What's `this.$http` being executed within? A component method? Does `console.log(this)` give you the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import`s are not inherited. Each module needs to import all the resources it needs.

Comment: It is not necessary in Vue to `import` vue-resource in a component that intends to use `this.$http`.

Comment: @Roy-J What does this mean??

Comment: @mesqueeb If module c imports module b, and module b imports module a, and module c needs something in module a, module c still needs to import module a. It does not get it by importing module b.